# Can a fast blow fuse with higher current rating affect motor's performance?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, fuses

I have an old blender that I wanted to use after a couple of years. When I turned it on, it was functional for about half a minute and then stopped working.

When I took it apart, I found that the fuse was blown (slow T 500 mA, 250 V) so I took it out and because I thought that perhaps the fuse was just old and went when it shouldn't have, I wanted to try it with another one. Since I only had a fast one at hand and its rated current was much higher (1.6 A), I put it in there and turned the blender on, however the motor didn't appear to be working and instead produced low noise. The second fuse wasn't damaged.

My question is whether a fast fuse in place of a slow one can affect a motor's performance based on speed or higher rated current. If not, what could be the source of the problem?

Could there be an unrelated electrical problem that had caused the first fuse to blow but since the second can take much higher current, it now only overloads the motor?

Thank you.

(Note that I wasn't planning on using the 1.6 A fuse long-term; it was just to test if the rest was working correctly.)

Comment: Most likely, unrelated electrical problem caused the fuse to fail.

Answer (score 4):

The fuse is a safety device, it should not effect the normal operation of the appliance. it should only have effect in a fault.

It sounds like the motor failed, possibly seized bearings, or a short-circuited rotor winding.